# For which $a$ value can not be the eigenvalue equal to $2$ for the following matrix? $\begin{pmatrix} 1&a&-1 \\ -2&1&0 \\ a&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$ii$,For which $a$ value does the matrix have any eigenvalues?

I have calculated the value of the characteristics polynomial which is equal to $-x^3+3x^2-3x+1-3ax+3a$.

After that I substitued $a=2$ which gave me that $x^3+3x^2-9x+7=0$ and as a root I got $x \approx-5.0546$. I'm pretty not sure about it, that my solution is correct.

How can I solve the second ($ii$) question? Do I have to find roots of the polynomial of $-x^3+3x^2-3x+1-3ax+3a$?

Comment: what question $(ii)$?

Comment: For which $a$value does not have the matrix an eigenvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The charactheristic polynomial tends to positive infinity as $x \to -\infty$. The charactheristic polynomial tends to negative infinity as $x \to \infty$.

By intermediate value theorem, there is always a root, and hence an eigenvalue.

I believe the question is whether the eigenvalue is equal to $2$.

You should not substitute $a=2$, rather you should substitute $x=2$.

Comment: and how can I check for which $a$ does the matrix have no eigenvalues? Every square matrix has a characteristic polynomial. In the domain of real numbers, not every polynomial has real roots and so not every matrix has an eigenvalue, eigenvector pair. Do I have to find a characteristic polynomial which has only complex roots?

Comment: Your characteristic polynomial is cubic, it always has a real root.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues are $1$, $1-\sqrt{-3a}$, and $1+\sqrt{-3a}$. An eigenvalue is equal to $2$ if and only if $a=-1/3$.

Comment: Is there any way, which helps me to get "easily" the eigenvalues? I just still looking after the answer for which $a$ does the matrix have no eigenvalues and I would like to see it exactly

Comment: The eigenvalues are the roots of the characteristic polynomial. In your case, this polynomial is $1 + 3 a - 3 \lambda - 3 a \lambda + 3 \lambda^2 - \lambda^3=(1-\lambda)(1+3a-2\lambda+\lambda^2)$. Every polynomial of degree greater than 1 has roots and, hence, every matrix has eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

i have computet $$1,1+\sqrt{-3a},1-\sqrt{-3a}$$ i think there is a mistake

Comment: Really, I made a mistake

Comment: a nice Name "Zauberkerl"